# How to configure Feign client to work without Consul

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-feign, spring-cloud-consul

Can someone help to find out why I can't setup locally `FeignClient` using `application.properties` and without running consul?

client:

```
@FeignClient(value = "my-service", configuration = FeignConfig.class) {
  ...
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.cloud.consul.config.enabled=false
my-service.ribbon.listOfServers=127.0.0.1:8091
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage to configure `@FeignClient` too work with hardcoded address using these configs in `aplication.properties` :

```
<service-name>.ribbon.listOfServers=<ip:port>
spring.cloud.bus.enabled=false
spring.cloud.consul.discovery.enabled=false
spring.cloud.consul.enabled=false
```